# Nusoap - fix empty xmlns attribute for the response

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

i have created a simple web service using Php Nusoap. its working correctly but the only thing missing is to add the default xmlns attribute to the response tag.

Here is the copy of Response :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <LoginResponse xmlns="">
      <LoginResult>
        <register>
          <customer>d2ff3b88d34705e01d150c21fa7bde07</customer>
        </register>
      </LoginResult>
    </LoginResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the code :

```
<?php

require_once ('nusoap.php');
// set namespace
$ns = 'mynamspace';
// set up soap server
$server = new soap_server ();
$server->configureWSDL ( 'testservice', $ns);
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns;
// define new user data type


// define results


$server->wsdl->addComplexType ( 'customer', 'complexType', 'struct', '', '', array ('customer' => array ('name' => 'customer', 'type' => 'xsd:string' ) ) );
$server->wsdl->addComplexType ( 'register', 'complexType', 'struct', '', '', array ('register' => array ('name' => 'register', 'type' => 'tns:customer' ) ) );
$server->wsdl->addComplexType ( 'LoginResult', 'complexType', 'struct', '', '', array ('LoginResult' => array ('name' => 'LoginResult', 'type' => 'tns:register' ) ) );

// register Login function
$server->register ( 'Login', // method name
array ('username' => 'xsd:string', 'password' => 'xsd:string' ), // input parameters
array ('LoginResult' => 'tns:register' ), // output parameters
'urn:mynamespace', // namespace
'urn:mynamespaceAction', // soapaction
'document', // style
'literal', // use
'Login service for testing' ); // documentation


function Login($username, $password) {
    if (isset ( $username ) && isset ( $password )) {
        $hash = md5 ( $username );
        return array ('LoginResult' => array ('register' => array ('customer' => $hash ) ));

    } 
}

// Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset ( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service ( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA );
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim this is particularly elegant, but worked in my case:

I went into the nusoap.php and commented this line (line 5925 for me):

//$elementNS = " xmlns=\"\"";

directly after this:
if ($unqualified && $use == 'literal') {

Comment: Thanks a lot Lee, i used the same approach.